# Magento 2.3.1 - Update Cart Quantity Empties Cart when pressing ENTER

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, shopping

I have just updated to Magento 2.3.1 and noticed that whenever a customer goes to his cart and changes the quantity of an item and press ENTER, then the whole cart gets empty instead to updating the new quantity. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Can you check your system / exception logs when u have redone the action to see if there are any errors which popup maybe check your network panel for any errors

Comment: I have installed a fresh magento 2.3.1 with sample data and it does exactly the same.

Comment: When you click the update button does it reset (not pressing enter)

Comment: also are you working locally if so change your base url localhost to 127.0.0.1 or map a local url via your host file also check your using http only in the sytem config

Comment: Hi Dava, Update button works. But some people don't necessarily scroll down to update when they have a long list. My intuition is to change the number and click "Enter". I have a live website and a test website that is on 2 differents siteground hosting package.

Comment: I will setup a development enviroment for this to test if it is a standard 2.3 issue or if it is extension/theme related

Comment: Apparently this is an issue with the updated 2.3.1. Also my test website has no extentions or themes. It is purely a magento 2.3.1 with sample data. I could message you the cpanel and admin credentials so you can see

Comment: Hi, I found something on Github but I have not idea how to fix it. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21499

Comment: You theme may require a bit of a rewrite as i can confirm that this issue was fixed in 2.3 and have installed a test version to duplicate the issue and cannot so possible u have that JS within your theme already and its using an older version

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below steps to fix this issue an alternative way.

copy the **form.phtm**l file from a vendor directory and paste it in your current theme. Swap the buttons code in the template file as shown below & clear flush cache and test it.

**From Vendor:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**  @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid */
?>
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
              {"validationURL" : "/checkout/cart/updateItemQty"}
          }'
          class="form form-cart">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="cart table-wrapper<?= $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : '' ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-top toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-top"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table"
               class="cart items data table"
               data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": ".action.clear",
               "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Cart Items') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Item') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-bottom toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart main actions">
        <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
            <a class="action continue"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-empty=""
                value="empty_cart"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-item-update=""
                value="update_qty"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action update">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
    </div>
</form>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after') ?>
```

**To Theme directory:**

> app/design/frontend/Kensium/learning/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**  @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid */
?>
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
              {"validationURL" : "/checkout/cart/updateItemQty"}
          }'
          class="form form-cart">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="cart table-wrapper<?= $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : '' ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-top toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-top"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table"
               class="cart items data table"
               data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": ".action.clear",
               "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Cart Items') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Item') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-bottom toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart main actions">
        <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
            <a class="action continue"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
       <!--  Swap the positions of buttons here -->     

        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-item-update=""
                value="update_qty"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action update">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
       <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-empty=""
                value="empty_cart"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
    </div>
</form>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that this solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following and run setup upgrade and di:compile

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendorname/module-modulename",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "email": "you@youremail.com",
            "name": "Your Name"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "VendorName\\ModuleName\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/register.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/shopping-cart':
            'VendorName_ModuleName/js/shopping-cart'
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/shopping-cart.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.shoppingCart', {
        /** @inheritdoc */
        _create: function () {
            var items, i;

            $(this.options.emptyCartButton).on('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
                if (event.detail === 0) {
                    return;
                }

                $(this.options.emptyCartButton).attr('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                $(this.options.updateCartActionContainer)
                    .attr('name', 'update_cart_action').attr('value', 'empty_cart');
            }, this));
            items = $.find('[data-role="cart-item-qty"]');

            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                $(items[i]).on('keypress', $.proxy(function (event) { //eslint-disable-line no-loop-func
                    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

                    if (keyCode == 13) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                        $(this.options.emptyCartButton).attr('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                        $(this.options.updateCartActionContainer)
                            .attr('name', 'update_cart_action').attr('value', 'update_qty');

                    }
                }, this));
            }
            $(this.options.continueShoppingButton).on('click', $.proxy(function () {
                location.href = this.options.continueShoppingUrl;
            }, this));
        }
    });

    return $.mage.shoppingCart;
});
```

This will overwrite the core magento checkout shopping-cart.js and fix the issue you are having.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above and it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: You do have a theme it is just the standard luma/blank theme loaded from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma and all the different pieces are within the individual modules. if u replace the static content version of this to test and then if it does work create a custom module with this in place. never update vendor

Comment: did u delete your cache also make sure you deleted your browser cache as i found that for some reason chrome and firefox cache the js files

Comment: I actually tried to test your code by changing in vendor folder and it works. i guess I just have to find a way to incorporate this in my theme. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I have tried to add it in my <Theme>/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/shopping-cart.js. Static-content:deploy, Clean Cache, Flush cache, remove pub/static, Generated/code, var/viewprocessed, Var/Cache, Static-content:deploy again...the code don't seem to overwrite the core magento checkout shopping-cart.js. Is it really bad to change the vendor folder? At this point I am so discouraged.

Comment: In the name of testing do it in vendor and then once it has been tested and working you should revert and i will advise on a easier way of overwriting it

Comment: I did it in Vendor and it is working. Can you tell what is the easier way to overwrite without touching the core files?

Comment: @JamesTsai please check my revised answer, change VendorName to something and change ModuleName to something

Comment: Hi Dava, I have done exactly your revised answer. I checked 3 times to make sure, did the setup:upgrade, compile, static-content, clear cache, flush cache and used an incongnito browser (both on explorer and chrome) to test. Unfortunately it is still emptying my cart.

Comment: @JamesTsai but it did work when you placed in vendor? if then possible might need to set sequensing to load after checkout

Comment: I am also facing the same issue can u please suggest https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uHFdp9tSAkioF09-fSDuTydcIsykELOz/view

Comment: @NagarajuKasa please try implimenting my answer also make sure your sequensing is correct so the module loads after the code base in vendor

Comment: Hi @Dav Gordon I have tried your answer but no luck.

Comment: do you have a link so i can take a look at this for myself

Comment: Is this working in Magento 2.3.0 and lower version?

Comment: Works on 2.2.8 and above

Answer (score 0):

Just thought it was worth sharing that this a core bug:

Fix can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21509/files

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this issue you have to know that on a html form the first element witch has type submit on it will be called when "enter" is hit. So in magento the first element on the form with type submit is the clear button. To solve this issue you can modify the order of the buttons in Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml ( put update button before clear button)